# How to retrieve Bitcoin transfer unconfirmed for 10 days

Tags: transactions

I’m very new to Bitcoin. I had Bitcoin sent to wallet on Bitcoin.com and then sent to wallet in cash app that I am familiar with. After 12 days it still says unconfirmed and pending. Is there a way to resend and pay higher fee or what can I do to have access and be able to cash in and use money? Please help!! [image]

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is for you to never use bitcoin.com.  This is a scammy site which attempts to trick new users into thinking that something called "bitcoin cash" or the ticker "bch" is bitcoin. Which it is not.

But luckily the bitcoin that you bought is the real bitcoin (often referred to as btc)

By now, your transaction has probably confirmed and already reached your wallet since the activity on the network has calmed down now over the weekend.

If not, it is usually possible to use something called "Replace By Fee" or "RBF", which increases the fee that you pay for your transaction so that it will get included in a block, and thus reach your faster.

If you are interested, consider to visit bitcoin.org to find out all the details about how to install your own bitcoin node and wallet in order to increase your security and not need to trust Cashapp for holding your funds.